# What do I tell my child about her Asperger autism?

Tags: autism, special-needs, asperger

My child has Asperger's syndrome. She is high-grade enough that she has been going through school and she speaks and sort of makes eye-contact, but it is clear to her and everyone that she is 'different', and she needs help.

She has been asking for some time "what is wrong with me?"

She is 13. Teenage socialisation and sexualisation are next...

How do I tell her what it means to have AS?

Comment: There's already been a number of excellent resources mentioned. To add to that, you may check out the parent support resources from the [Asperger/Autism Network](http://www.aane.org/aane_services/aane_online_support_groups.html) or Wrongplanet.net.

Comment: Also there are many parts (like the 'technical' parts about  sex) that work the same in people with ASS. For the most part you can talk to them the same way about the risk of getting pregnant if she didn't have ASS

Answer (score 13, accepted):

She can discern that she's different from other kids her age. She's expressing this in a way that's heartbreaking for me to even read, let alone to deal with as a parent. As hard as it is, the time has come to validate her suspicions. If she didn't need some sort of validation, she wouldn't be asking you. At the risk of sounding chiché-ish, it's time for her to live with Autism Spectrum Disorder as part of who she is and not as something to be afraid of. Be aware, though, that this is a difficult time [for kids to hear that they are different](https://web.archive.org/web/20130107042358/http://autismdigest.com/10-guidelines-about-asd/).

There are famous and successful people with ASD, for example, look at the immense relief of animal suffering thanks to [Temple Grandin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_Grandin). [Susan Boyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susan_Boyle) has blessed the world with her beautiful voice. (If you've never seen her *Britain's Got Talent* debut, you really should; it's a bit painful but it's a huge -and tear-inducing - wake-up call.) There is so much awareness of and support for ASD that the diagnosis no longer carries the stigma it once did, and help dealing with issues such as this one is not difficult to find.

If you're not familiar with [Autisticadvocacy.org](http://autisticadvocacy.org/), please visit the site. There is a wealth of information for families, including for adolescents. I don't know what kind of therapy she's been receiving, but there is a ton of evidence that treatment helps with social skills, etc. The journal *Autism* may be available by request at your library. It's a great source of information, including dealing with issues such as this one.

> [T]he possibility of problems occurring is more likely when someone is not told about their disability,sup>* and given the support they need... Not understanding others or social situations for many leads to poor interactions with others and results in ridicule and isolation... *You can look for the presence of certain signs that the child is ready for information.* Some children will actually ask, “What is wrong with me?,” “Why can’t I be like everybody else?,” “Why can’t I _____?,” or even “What is wrong with everyone?” These types of questions are certainly a clear indication that they need some information about their diagnosis. - [Getting Started: Introducing Your Child to His or Her Diagnosis of Autism or Asperger Syndrome](http://www.iidc.indiana.edu/pages/Getting-Started-Introducing-Your-Child-to-His-or-Her-Diagnosis-of-Autism-or-Asperger-Syndrome)

I would recommend you read the source above.

You may want to break the information up into parts, and tell your child that this is going to be ongoing dialogue. (If your child had a newly diagnosed cardiac problem, wouldn't this also be true?) What is your daughter's preferred learning style? If she likes books, many are available for you and that you might read a book together, such as (among others) [Freaks, Geeks & Asperger Syndrome: A User Guide to Adolescence](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2542912/) written by a 13 year old male with Asperger’s, who was able to address problems kids with this diagnosis commonly face. If she likes movies and videos, there's no shortage of these either. The talk needs to come first, though, before the exploration.

*<sub>Not my words.</sub>

<sub>These aren't my usual scholarly-type recommendations, but they address your question.</sub>

<sub>[Top 10 Autism Websites Recommended by Parents](http://eden2.org/top-10-autism-websites-recommended-by-parents/)</sub>
<sub>[Parent Tips: "You Have Autism."](http://www.pathfindersforautism.org/articles/view/parent_tips_you_have_autism)</sub>
<sub>[Your child has autism. How (and when) do you tell him?](http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/parenting/wp/2014/05/27/your-child-has-autism-how-and-when-do-you-tell-him/)</sub>
<sub>[10 Guidelines for Telling Your Child about ASD](https://web.archive.org/web/20130107042358/http://autismdigest.com/10-guidelines-about-asd/)</sub>

Comment: How about support groups, both for the parents (to talk about how to tell her, etc.) and for the daughter (to meet peers who are "like" her)?

Comment: Support groups are highly recommended. Most of the references give such information; *Autism Speaks* even breaks up all of the thousands of groups and other resources state by state.

Comment: Great answer, I'd only add don't make it a big deal.

Comment: As a parent of a child with Autism, I've heard a lot of negative things about Autism Speaks.  [1] https://medium.com/@KirstenSchultz/a-roundup-of-posts-against-autism-speaks-5dbf7f8cfcc6 

I'd recommend ASAN instead [2] http://autisticadvocacy.org, who's members are on the spectrum and know what it's like.  Preferably their focus on "defense mode" practical sessions are more effective than the pablum that Autism Speaks seems to trumpet

Comment: @r00fus - OK, thanks. I'll edit and look into it.

Comment: Two of my good friends and my husband all have AS, and I have one thing to add here (though I think this answer is overall good): all three of them have come to see it as a differently organized mind, rather than a disability, and all three feel grossly misunderstood when their AS is classified as a disability. It’s more of a “You have AS which means your brain works differently from other people’s. Here’s how...”

Comment: @MAA - I don't think Autism is a disability. I know a lot of people with mild to moderate autism, and they are all what anyone would consider "successful people". Did I say it was a disability? I didn't mean to imply that. It's different, and it is a disorder. I see it's in the quote I posted. Not my words.

Comment: in my trade (IT programming) its a positive advantage. My two asperger kids are respectively great mathematician and great artist. Lots of people are and don't even know it. We find ways of coping like emotion flash cards, finding other ASD kids is worthwhile too.

Comment: Microsoft is actively seeking out people on the ASD spectrum because they can often solve certain classes of problem better than traditional teams.

Comment: Speaking personally, being told I was different in identifiable, nameable ways from other people was empowering; it meant I now had the words to think and talk about what was happening and how I felt. Before I just had this awareness of being wrong in some undefinable way. (Note: my differences are MUCH less significant than AS; YMMV)

Comment: @anongoodnurse Autism Speaks is basically an anti-autism hate group with Hollywood and government connections that pretends to be a pro-autism advocacy group. As an autistic person, I'm asking you to please remove the link to them.

Comment: @nick012000 - I have no evidence that what you say is true, and in this case, asking for a reliable source seems appropriate. Before linking to *any* site, I combed this site over pretty thoroughly (I daresay more thoroughly than most people who use and cite sources.) That was  several years ago. I don't link to unreliable sources or unethical ones. Your accusation is significant enough to warrant proof. (It sounds somewhat like "deep state" rumors.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse Okay, here's a Youtube video about them: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Va_XXoD5LE It's by a Youtuber who usually does videos exposing multilevel marketing scams.

Comment: @anongoodnurse You can find a list of links to various posts against Autism Speaks here: https://medium.com/@KirstenSchultz/a-roundup-of-posts-against-autism-speaks-5dbf7f8cfcc6   An article by a "real" support group on Autism Speaks is here: https://www.altogetherautism.org.nz/autism-no-puzzle-nothing-wrong-with-us/

Comment: @anongoodnurse And here is what autisticadvocacy.org, the other side you link, has to say about Autism Speaks: https://autisticadvocacy.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/AutismSpeaksFlyer2020.pdf

Comment: @nick012000 - I don't watch youtube videos for proof of anything, maybe to my discredit. I did read Arno's links. I also revisited the site, putting myself in the place of a parent with an autistic child. I agree with the seeming negativism of portrayal of autistic people. If that  is meant to cause sympathy and donations, then it is indeed reprehensible, on the level of PETA. Removed.

Comment: @Arno - Thanks for your information presented without hyperbole.

Comment: There are many good things are said, and I just need to add that, when you give information, you should not sound that it is whole identity. When someone has diabetes, we do not call this person the one with the diabetes his here. So, she is bigger than that. It is just something she has, not she is.

Comment: @BaharAykaç - I agree someone is more than their diagnosis, but as a physician, I assure you that we do identify patients as "diabetics", "asthmatics", etc., not as "whole persons with this particular aspect to them." Compartmentalization is necessary.  The same applies to answers about a particular aspect of a person. The answer addresses the concern, in this case autism. It's no different in that respect than addressing a parent of a child child with, say, a fear of flying. We limit our answers to that concern.

Comment: I think a parent should not do this to their children or people to themselves, I just say that when explaining parents avoid giving that impression that this diagnosis is going to be her everything. Because it can happen. As a physician, of course you do, because your job is to find a cure to the that concern. But I think if your patients label themselves " diabetics", it sounds not healthy to me, because it is limiting a whole identity to a single part.

Comment: @BaharAykaç - Your insistence sounds quite strange to me. When I'm being questioned about my health, I do identify myself by my diagnoses. It  doesn't diminish me, because  as I said in my first response - and nowhere said otherwise -  a person is more than their diagnoses. The answer stands as it addresses the parent's issue as stated.

Answer (score 3):

The first important thing is obviously to move the tone of the conversation from "What is wrong with me?" to "In what ways am I different from neurotypical people?". The latter then is not something where you tell her, but rather where you assist her in figuring out the answer (and listen to what she says about it).

It may already be comforting to her to talk about common characteristics of people on the autism spectrum, so that she can see that some things she currently considers as she being weird are perfectly normal (but just not for neurotypical people).

A typical example of the "just different" aspects is eye contact. Painting with a broad brush, neurotypicals like eye contact and people on the spectrum do not much care about it. There is nothing intrinsically virtuous about eye contact. That your daughter is actively trying to make eye contact is thus not her coping with a disability, but her going out of her way to make others comfortable - a very polite and considerate thing to do, which she should be proud of!

To make sure that "just different" doesn't become a euphemism. it is important to also be honest about inherent disadvantages. For example, if her sensor overload threshold is sufficiently low for it to be triggered in everyday situations, it is a real problem and deserving of a coping strategy. It is not a good reason for shame though. If it just means that she couldn't stand being in a nightclub, then it may suffice for her to understand that tropes like "teenagers love going to nightclubs" are not prescriptive, and that there are plenty of other ways to have a fulfilling teenagerhood.

Following from that last thought, for both you and her it will be helpful to keep in mind that most representations in the media as well as advice texts about how humans function are concerned with neurotypical humans only. Thus, both of you will need to discern carefully what is and what is not applicable to her. This is not her fault for "not adhering to factory specifications", but for those representations etc to not cover the true variety of humans.

Finally, let me repeat the point made in several comments that there is a significant overlap between "typical characteristics of mathematicians and computer science people" and "typical characteristics of people on the autism spectrum". This contributes to a culture I'd consider to be rather more comfortable to people on the spectrum than the mainstream. Even if this subjects aren't particularly her thing, just knowing of this might help her in accepting herself as she is.

Comment: I very much like this approach. Although I use *different* as well, it's much clearer and cleaner in your post. +1

Answer (score -1):

I think the thing is, don't worry too much about labels, ie whether your daughter understands herself that she 'is' or 'isn't' aspergers. Just try to assist your daughter with their specific needs

How she sees herself in terms of labels isn't what matters (I think), but rather how she understands her own needs. For instance, if she has trouble interacting with people, is that because she has trouble understanding and reading peoples emotions? If thats the case, then maybe approach the issue as discussion on peoples emotions, and explanations of how those work, helping her understand how to read them. And if she cannot grasp how to read or understand others' emotions, then help her undrestand that those are aspects other people communicate by that she cannot see

So, its not so important what you call her, whether you tell her shes Aspergers or not, but rather the specific situation

What can go wrong, though if she is aspergers she might not pick it up, is if you have any personal notions of stigmatization coming through in that

I can kinda relate. I am somewhat on the autistic spectrum. However, I did not find out until I was in my late twenties and that my mom (and others) considered me so. But I do appreciate that no one really made a big deal out of it or whatnot

Comment: like my comment on your other post: this is not a discussion forum, so please don't post like it is. Read our [about] and [answer] pages, and look at highly upvoted posts to see what we expect.

Comment: Ok, I will try. But I don't understand exactly what you mean in terms of the difference between a discussion vs an answere. Is this an issue of content or an issue of format? Am I not giving information asked for, or am I not saying it correct? For instance, do I need to change 'The main thing is my parents appreciated me and didn't label or classify me. Everyone is different' to 'Don't label her. Just assist her with her unique needs and explain her specific needs without emphasizing any notions that she is weird or deficient' ?

Comment: Hi Rory, I have edited my answere to [this](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/41187/is-it-normal-for-a-child-just-turned-3-to-be-able-to-read-and-how-do-i-develop-a) question again. Would you be willing to review it and possibly undelete it if its still not satisfactory? Otherwise, if you could explain to me how to fix it I would appreciate it